# Mimic's adhesive

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters

I discovered that [mimics](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/aberrations/mimic) have a natural adhesive:

> A mimic exudes a thick slime that acts as a powerful adhesive, holding
>   fast any creatures or items that touch it. An adhesive-covered mimic
>   automatically grapples any creature it hits with its slam attack.
>   Opponents so grappled cannot get free while the mimic is alive without
>   removing the adhesive first. [...] A mimic can dissolve its adhesive
>   at will, and the substance breaks down 5 rounds after the creature
>   dies.

But I have a lot of questions about how it actually works:

- What happens if the opponents try grapple checks to escape? Do they fail automatically?
- Is the mimic considered grappled?
- Can the mimic keep on attacking other creatures with its slam attack?
- How many creatures can the mimic grapple at once?
- What kind of action is "dissolving its adhesive"?

Comment: I realised just now that your first bullet point is ambiguous. When you ask about opponents trying grapple checks, are you asking what happens if someone *initiates* a grapple against a mimic, or are you asking what happens if someone tries to *escape* a grapple the mimic initiated?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie fixed! And I also added a bullet point that I forgot

Comment: This question has too many questions, to be honest.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- This one's pretty clear. Opponents so grappled **cannot get free** while the mimic is alive without removing the adhesive first.
- There is no reason to consider the mimic grappled. While normally initiating a grapple causes you to also gain the grappled condition, this is not the mimic grappling normally. Rather, it is an ability the mimic has that simply inflicts the grappled condition on others. If the mimic did grapple normally using a grapple maneuver, then it would gain the grappled condition.
- Yes. In fact, it could do this even if it did have the grappled condition. Being grappled places no restrictions on who you can attack.
- There's no RAW limitation on the number of creatures that can get stuck to the mimic at a time. If they can reach it and touch it, they can be grappled by it.

So how do you remove the adhesive? Per the Adhesive ability:

> Strong alcohol or universal solvent dissolves the adhesive

Per the description for universal solvent:

> This substance has the unique property of being able to dissolve sovereign glue, tanglefoot bags, and all other adhesives. Applying the solvent is a standard action.

By extension, applying "strong alcohol" should take the same type of action.

And what can the mimic do? On the mimic's turn, it must roll CMB if it wishes to move, damage one of the creatures it has grappled (with a grapple check, rather than a standard attack), or pin one of the creatures it has grappled. Normally, if it failed this roll, the creature would break free. The adhesive ability clearly prevents that, so instead nothing happens. As stated earlier, it can also attack normally if it wishes.

Comment: I realised I was answer from a d20 SRD reading not a PRD reading, so I've deleted my answer. However, I maintain that the mimic *is* grappled is correct: "An adhesive-covered mimic automatically grapples" is not saying that it merely inflicts the grappled condition directly, it is saying that *it grapples*. The "automatically" doesn't alter what state follows, only how the state is brought about.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie is correct - the ability does not explicitly state that the Mimic isn't grappled. No, it doesn't make sense. Welcome to RAW.

Comment: It does not explicitly state that it is grappled either, is what I'm saying. In the end, as usual, it's up to the GM to decide.

Comment: It doesn't actually have to. That's part of grappling; the mimic 'automatically grapples' and becomes grappled as a normal part of grappling.

Answer (score 6):

> What happens if the opponents try grapple checks to escape? Do they fail automatically?

A [Mimic](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/aberrations/mimic)'s grapple works as any other grapple, but it triggers automatically (similar to the [grab ability](http://[grab%20ability][5])) when they attack *and* you cannot escape without either killing the mimic or removing the adhesive. That's the only difference.

> Is the mimic considered grappled?

Unless stated otherwise, yes. See, for example, the [Kraken](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/magical-beasts/kraken/), which doesn't get the grappled condition when they grapple with their tentacles.

> Can the mimic keep on attacking other creatures with its slam attack?

Nothing in the ability says otherwise, so it works like the [regular grapple](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Gamemastering/Combat/#TOC-Grapple): they take a penalty on their attack roll (from the [grappled](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Grappled) condition) and may attack anyone within range.

> How many creatures can the mimic grapple at once?

Just like grapple, the limit is normally your number of free appendages. Normally, you are also restricted by your action economy, as maintaining a grapple is usually a *standard action*, you don't have a second standard action to start another grapple.

Creatures with the [grab ability](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules/#Grab_Ex) may bypass that restriction by *using* the appendage to hold the grapple, removing their ability to use that appendage while the grapple lasts and not being able to attack with it.

The mimic may bypass those restrictions since the grappled is stuck to the mimic's body instead of being held by an appendage. So, the mimic may grapple as many creatures as they are able to make attacks against.

> What kind of action is "dissolving its adhesive"?

Should be a Standard Action for *applying an oil* or substance to dissolve it, as noted under [Using Magic Items](http://TOC-Using-Items) and on the [actions table](http://TOC-Action-Types). This is the case for applying an [Alchemical Solvent](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/goods-and-services/herbs-oils-other-substances/#TOC-Alchemical-Solvent), for instance, but each method may have different requirements.

Comment: I'm pretty curious about one thing : the mimic is grappled and there be possibly a bunch of creatures grappled with it. So does the mimics attack penalty due to it being grappled stack for each grappled creature or apply only one time ?

Comment: The penalty is caused by the *grappled* condition, and conditions dont stack, he isnt "grappled" multiple times, he is "grappled".

Comment: It's a shame that as soon as a mimic grabs something it can no longer AoO said thing's allies.

Comment: On the last point, 'dissolving its adhesive', I believe the querent may have been referring to the mimic's own at-will ability to dissolve its own adhesive.